# How to copy 1 column from a CSV file to a SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, csv

I got a CSV file but in the files in using there are not comma seperaters in the file.
How can I copy this data into my database? So the CSV file and thus the database should have 1 column.

This is what I tried so far:

```
System.Data.DataTable csvData = new System.Data.DataTable();
try
{
    using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250"))) //windows 1250 is de correcte character encoding voor europese characters 
    {
        csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," }); //change this maybe to something???
        csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
        foreach (string column in colFields)
        {
            DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
            datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
            csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
        }
         while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
            //Making empty value as null
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fieldData[i] == "")
                {
                    fieldData[i] = null;
                }
            }
            csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData); // it return an error here saying that: `System.ArgumentException: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table`
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(csvData, tablenaam);
return csvData;
```

So an example for the CSV would be:

```
test123    
test45,6    
test789
```

And in my database would be the exact same values.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean by a CSV file "without comma separeting". Can you provide an example of the data you are importing?

Comment: @MaurizioPozzobon Ye, now that I read it again its indeed a bit vague. I am reading a CSV but the CSV's im reading doenst contain any comma seperatings, so thats why I will only have 1 column in my database file. I added an example in my question

Comment: Can you debug it and see how many columns are found in colFields, I mean, fieldData.Length == ??

Comment: if your file has those | and - signs in, you would need to do more work.. but what problem are you having in loading in your data putting it to sql if its only got 1 value, its not csv, its just a text file

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca The fieldData.Lenth depends on each row which in reading. You want to know what the fieldData.Length is at the error or?

Comment: @BugFinder there are `|` and `-` characters in my CSV file

Comment: my code is probably way too implicated, there is most likely a easier way to do this with much less code

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. I dont see any errors...

Comment: Can you add the whole exception please?

Comment: Can a streamReader read an txt file?

Comment: Yes, @wouterdejong it can.

Comment: @BugFinder The problem is, when it meets an comma in the CSV, it gives an error with the current code, because my database is only 1 column wide, and it want to split the text in the CSV to 2 columns because of the comma `,`

Comment: but your example has no commas in, I think you will fail to get the answer you need until we have the info we need to help you, and there are zero commas in your example, only ansi boxes drawn round them..

Comment: @BugFinder haha, those `-` and `|` were actually just to show that it is a table

Comment: Right - which is why we have all been asking for your format.. so you have irregular csv entries.. thats never a good thing... you really need to read them in and sort your data into normalised stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: read the comment about actual delimeters so I've updated the code below, is not pretty but should give you a starting point

Why not read the file as a simple text file. One line at a time and parse the expected syntax.

Doing something like this (not tested, may not compile)

```
string line;
System.Data.DataTable csvData = new System.Data.DataTable();
csvData.Columns.Add("OnlyColumn", typeof(String));
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if(line.StartsWith("-"))
        continue;        
    DataRow newRow = csvData.NewRow();
    newRow["OnlyColumn"] = line.Split('|')[1].Trim();
    csvData.Rows.Add(newRow);
}

file.Close();
InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(csvData, tablenaam);
```

Comment: I get an error @ `if(line.StartsWith('-'))` : `cannot convert from char to string`

Comment: this works `if (line.StartsWith("-"))
                    continue;` but i get the error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Column 'OnlyColumn' does not belong to table

Comment: You have to add the column to the data table, I've edited the sample, but you should view it as a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use new line as delimiter not comma. I think you can have new values in new lines?

Comment: I tried `csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }); `and `csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "\n" );` , but those doenst work. I get the error: `System.ArgumentException: TextfieldParser does not support delimiters that contain end-of-line characters`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use `StreamReader.ReadLine()` for this

You should check out this link for an explanation from Microsoft.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

So something like this should do it:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csv_file_path)) 
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        csvData.Rows.Add(new string[] {sr.ReadLine()});
    }
}
```